# How to redirect to another component using link in Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```html
<div class="enterprise-details" style="margin-top: 20px">
Already have an account? <a href="#"> LOGIN</a></div>
```

```html
 <!--  Component which need to redirect -->

<b-button v-if="!registeredUser" class="button-self" v-b-modal.modal-x>Login</b-button>
 <b-modal
      id="modal-x" ref="my-modal"
      title=""
      class="modal-dialog modal-sm modal-rounded fade"
      
    >
    //some code
    
    </b-modal>
```

onclick Of link, How to redirect the page to another component

Comment: Seems that you want to use https://router.vuejs.org/

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use the official [Vue Router](https://router.vuejs.org/)

Once you've [set your routes and told your vue instance to use the router](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/), replace your `<a href="#">` line with a `<router-link>` component:

```
<div class="enterprise-details" style="margin-top: 20px">
   Already have an account?<router-link to="/login">LOGIN</router-link>
</div>
```

Or, if you set up a [named route](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/named-routes.html), you can do it this way:

```
<div class="enterprise-details" style="margin-top: 20px">
   Already have an account?<router-link :to="{ name: 'login' }">LOGIN</a>
</div>
```

Read through the [docs here](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/).

Comment: Its working fine, but what if i want to call modal popup

Comment: If you are using a button to open a modal, then what you need is a `v-on:click` listener on a `<button>` element, not an anchor `<a>` element. In the method called on the click event, toggle a local data property e.g. `modalOpen`.

Comment: Can you please help with an example for the above. It will be helpful for me

Comment: There's an example provided in the official docs: https://vuejs.org/v2/examples/modal.html